# Get Field from another table

Tags: hibernate

I'm using Hibernate and Enver module to audit my tables.

On my table CAMPO I have:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "sequencial")
private Long sequencial;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "updated")
private LocalDateTime updated;
```

I want to show the content of my table (CAMPO) with Angular 7, **including the most recent REVTYPE field**, present only in the audit table called CAMPO_AUD. As I do not have an entity for my audit table, I need to work only with the entity of my CAMPO table. So I need to "call" REVTYPE inside my CAMPO entity.

I tried use formula like this:

```
@Formula("SELECT AUD.REVTYPE FROM CAMPO_AUD AUD WHERE AUD.UPDATED = (SELECT MAX(C.UPDATED) FROM CAMPO_AUD C WHERE AUD.ID = C.ID))")
@NotAudited
private long revType;
```

But its not working (nullpointer exception).

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.hibernate.loader.DefaultEntityAliases.intern(DefaultEntityAliases.java:176)
at org.hibernate.loader.DefaultEntityAliases.getSuffixedPropertyAliases(DefaultEntityAliases.java:135)
at org.hibernate.loader.DefaultEntityAliases.determinePropertyAliases(DefaultEntityAliases.java:77)
at org.hibernate.loader.DefaultEntityAliases.<init>(DefaultEntityAliases.java:49)
at org.hibernate.loader.ColumnEntityAliases.<init>(ColumnEntityAliases.java:26)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.generateCustomReturns(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:209)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLCustomQuery.<init>(SQLCustomQuery.java:136)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

1) I assume that AUD.REVTYPE can be null. There for you should use Long instead of long.

2) You have to add the id of the Campo entity to the where clause. so not C.ID but id

```
@Formula("SELECT AUD.REVTYPE FROM CAMPO_AUD AUD "+
         "WHERE AUD.UPDATED = (SELECT MAX(C.UPDATED) FROM CAMPO_AUD C " +
         "WHERE AUD.ID = id))")
@NotAudited
private long revType;
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58994659/get-field-from-another-table/58994920?noredirect=1#comment104241294_58994920